# Radio button not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<FormGroup controlId="gender">
  <ControlLabel>Gender</ControlLabel>
  <br />
  <Radio
    name="radioGroup"
    type="radio"
    inline
    value={this.state.gender === "male"}
  >
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    Male
  </Radio>
  <Radio
    name="radioGroup"
    type="radio"
    inline
    value={this.state.gender === "female"}
  >
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    Female
  </Radio>
</FormGroup>
```

code not working..unable to set the state using this code

Comment: radio is a react bootstrap component. m importing from react bootstrap like this import { Radio,FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel} from 'react-bootstrap';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your state define a gender object:

```
this.state = {
  gender: {
    male: 'male',
    female: 'female'
  }     
}
```

You set a boolean value in the radio 'value' field. Should be just:
    value={this.state.gender.male}

And the onChange should be in your Radio tag too.

```
<Radio name="radioGroup" 
       inline 
       value={this.state.gender.male}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
>
</Radio>
```

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: in state value of gender is blank like this  gender:" ",

Comment: Define it initially as I wrote above in this.state